# When a CSS selector matches N elements, how to get only the one at a certain index?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

Here's where I'm at:

```
// Running this CSS selector:
$(".contact-form form")

// Returns this:
// [form, form]
```

I want to be able to get the first of these forms only, or perhaps the second only.

I've tried to use some CSS pseudoselectors but nothing has worked:

```
$(".contact-form form:first-of-type")
// [form, form]

$(".contact-form form:nth-of-type(1)")
// [form, form]
```

I've also tried using these pseudoselectors on the `.contact-form` instead of the `form`:

```
$(".contact-form")
// [div.modal-inner.contact-form, div.modal-inner.contact-form]

$(".contact-form:first-of-type")
// [div.modal-inner.contact-form, div.modal-inner.contact-form]

$(".contact-form:nth-of-type(1)")
// [div.modal-inner.contact-form, div.modal-inner.contact-form]
```

I understand that I can use array indexing to get the first or second but I am hoping there is a way to do it using just the CSS selector. This is because I have an existing API that accepts input for the CSS selector, but doesn't process other jQuery instructions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) method, as documented:

> Retrieve one of the elements matched by the jQuery object.

```
$(".contact-form form").get(0)
```

This gives you the DOM element. If instead you want a jQuery object for the same, then use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

```
$(".contact-form form").eq(0)
```

So this is virtually equivalent to:

```
$($(".contact-form form").get(0))
```

There is no pure CSS solution for this, but jQuery has [its own extension of selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and supports things like [`:eq(n)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), [`:gt(n)`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/), [`:lt(n)`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/), [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), [`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/), [`:even`](https://api.jquery.com/even-selector/), [`:odd`](https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/), ...

Comment: Using jQuery on the 2-element array, I could also just use indexing `[0]`, which I realize. I suppose I didn't make this clear, but I am hoping there is a CSS only way to do this. The reason being that I have an existing API which _only_ accepts a CSS selector and doesn't process further jQuery instructions.

Comment: A pure CSS solution would be [`:nth-match`](http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/structural-pseudo-class/), but it has no browser support as of yet.

Comment: `:nth-match` was removed from the draft and only counted siblings, it didn't search in the entire tree.

Comment: thanks @trincot, this will save me keystrokes in the future as I now know it's not necessary to do `$($("form")[0])`

Answer (score 1):

> I have an existing API that accepts input for the CSS selector, but
>   doesn't process other jQuery instructions.

If by CSS selector you mean you can pass a string, perhaps you can use the [**`:eq()`**](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector, it's slower than `.eq()` because it's a jQuery selector *(not a CSS pseudo-selector)* that has to be parsed by the Sizzle selector library, but it does the same thing.

```
$(".contact-form form:eq(0)")
```